# WooCommerce Rest Api Android Library Issue (Woodroid)

Tags: android, android-studio, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I am using [woodroid library](https://github.com/gilokimu/WooDroid) for getting data from my wordpress woocommerce site into my android app following [this](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#libraries-and-tools). Now this library can only retrieve all the data together and then I  am able to show it. But I don't know why this way my app loads the data extremely slow. So I needed to fasten up the process by getting the values (As example products) one by one using the below code,

```
  val allProducts : MutableLiveData<Product> by lazy {
        woocommerce = Woocommerce.Builder().setSiteUrl(baseURL)
            .setApiVersion(Woocommerce.API_V2)
            .setConsumerKey(consumerKey)
            .setConsumerSecret(consumerSecret)
            .build()
        preLoadProducts()
        MutableLiveData<Product>()
    }

    private fun preLoadProducts() {
        val productFilter = ProductFilter()
        productFilter.page = pageNum
        productFilter.per_page = 1
        loadProducts(productFilter)
    }

    private fun loadProducts(productFilter: ProductFilter){
        woocommerce.ProductRepository().products(productFilter).enqueue(object :
            Callback<List<Product>> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Product>>, response: Response<List<Product>>) {
                try{
                    val productsResponse = response.body()
                    allProducts.value = productsResponse?.get(0)
                    pageNum ++
                    preLoadProducts()
                }catch (e : Exception){
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    allProducts.value = null
                }

            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Product>>, t: Throwable) {
                t.printStackTrace()
                allProducts.value = null
            }
        })
    }
```

Now I understand this is not the most efficient way to achieve this but it's working for me (Almost).
So I need a better and more efficient solution. If anyone has any idea, please help out.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is very close to what I do

I recommend using a library  [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging)

This library will do everything

Also, to save memory, use rxjava or coroutines for kotlin
This will help too

See this code in Java as it shows you how to fetch the complete data in a flexible manner that saves memory

---

```
@GET("wp-json/wc/v3/coupons?")
Observable<ArrayList<Coupons>> get_List_Codes(  @Query("page") int page, @Query("consumer_key") String consumer_key
        , @Query("consumer_secret") String consumer_secret);


Observable<ArrayList<Coupons>> getPageAndNext(int c) {

    return ClientApi.getInstance().get_List_Codes(count)
          ) )
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .concatMap(obsOld-> {

                if (obsOld.size() == 0) {
                   return Observable.just(obsOld);
                }
                else {
                    count ++;
                     return Observable.zip(Observable.just(obsOld)
                    ,getPageAndNext(count),(product11, product22) -> {
                                product11.addAll(product22);
                                return product11;
                            });

                }
            }
            );


}
```